# Additional Image Gallery in Product View

Tags: magento2

Does anyone know, how to add an additional gallery slider to a product? I want to show a second gallery below the page, to show more images.

Comment: What you have tried So far?

Comment: I was looking for an extension, but without any result. I have tried to do this with several attributes in Magento, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the steps described below to show additional image gallery on the product detail page

Assume you are using a custom theme "**Vendor_customtheme**".

**Step 1)** create ***/app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>                
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.extragallery" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/view/extra-gallery.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2)**

create ***/app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/catalog/product/view/extra-gallery.phtml***

```
<h2> Additional Image gallery</h2>
<ul  id="extra_gallery" class="fotorama" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li><img src="PATH-TO-IMAGE-1" /></li>
    <li><img src="PATH-TO-IMAGE-2" /></li>
    <li><img src="PATH-TO-IMAGE-3" /></li>
    <li><img src="PATH-TO-IMAGE-4" /></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
require ([
'jquery',
'mage/gallery/gallery'
], function ($, Gallery) {

    $(function () {
        // parse HTML to get client testimonials in array of objects
        var extragallerylsList = document.querySelectorAll("#extra_gallery li");
        var data = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < extragallerylsList.length; i++) {
            var obj = { html: extragallerylsList[i].outerHTML};
            data.push(obj);
        }

        $('#extra_gallery') // we expect that page contains markup tag with class .testimonials
            .each(function (index, element) {
                Gallery({
                    options: {
                        "nav": "dots",
                    },
                    data: data, // contains previously parsed testimonials
                    fullscreen: {}
                }, element); // 'element' is simgle DOM node.
        });        

    });  


});
</script>
```

step 3) Flush Magento cache

```
sudo php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how to upload images from the backend? Need to upload different images for each product.

Comment: That's a different question. You need to create a custom module for that. Thank you

Comment: Thank you ago. Do you have any link for a module/extension?